# Dealing with many unix processess/threads in example RabbitMQ app

Tags: ruby, multithreading, scala, process, rabbitmq

I playing with [rabbitmq tutorials](http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html). I create (in jruby) producer and several consumers, and to test it send simple text messages. I have open many terminals (one for each consumer) to get output. This is 'ugly' solution, what is better way to accomplish this?

I would like to get advice how to deal with it using linux programs, proccess, jruby thereads, threading, reactor pattern in general. Also Im eager to learn more about this topics. What are recommended readings (wikipedia, blog articles, books, free ebooks)?

Also examples are welcome!